# Ookla speedtest cli bypassing OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a VPN. All traffic is routed through it (`redirect-gateway def1`). If I try `curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'` I correctly read the IP address of the VPN server I'm connected to.

The routing tables looks fine (x.x.x.x is the VPN server IP).

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn# ip route show table main
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.200 metric 202
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
x.x.x.x via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.200 metric 202
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.1 metric 303
192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

When I'm using Ookla Speedtest CLI (https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli) it is clearly not routing the traffic through the VPN. The Provider name returned by the speedtest is the host ISP and the actual down/up speed are as high as the host without a VPN connection.

How can it be bypassing the VPN?

Comment: What OS is running on your Raspberry PI and which VPN client are you using?

Comment: So your VPN is set up to redirect the IPv4 routing, but what's in `ip -6 route`?

Comment: OpenVPN 2.5.1. Raspberry OS details as follows. Distributor ID: Debian - Description: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) - Release: 11 - Codename: bullseye

Answer (score 0):

Found out disabling IPv6 on my Raspberry will make all traffic going through the VPN tunnel.

/etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```